# Binding preloaded vuex data with dynamic vuetify v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am using VueJS 2.x and Vueitfy.

Scenario:
I have two select boxes, state and city. Based on the state, the city list is fetched. Ex: if you select Karanataka, all cities of karnataka are fetched in the second select box. For simplicity let's name them `stateSelect` and `citySelect`. I am triggering onChange event on stateSelect and calling fetch cities function. I have a two way binding with my Vuex store using computed property.

```
//store
export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
       mState: '',
       mCity: ''
   },
   mutations: {
        setState(state, mState){
            state.mState = mState;
        },
        setCity(state, mCity){
            state.mCity = mCity;
        },
   }
})

//component
computed: {
     state: {
         get(){
            return this.$store.state.mState;
         },
         set(val){
            this.$store.commit('saveState', val);
         }
     },
     city: {
         get(){
            return this.$store.state.mCity;
         },
         set(val){
            this.$store.commit('saveCity', val);
         }
     },
}

data(){
    return {
        states: [],
        cities: []
    }
}

methods: (
    getStates(), //fetches the list of states on mount
    getCities(stateId){
        //fetch cities based on selected state and convert it to a supported format
        this.cities = helpers.createSelectObj(response.data); //response is coming from an XHR request
    }
)
```

Problem:
Since I am using two-way binding, any selection change updates the Vuex as expected. But when the Vuex already has data, say if you navigate away from component and come back later, the state field gets automatically selected but the city fails to get selected. Instead the `mCity` in Vuex sets to null automatically.

Desired output:
After a state is selected, the cities must get fetched (as it happens already) but when on navigating from component and coming back to it, the state and city, both shall get seleceted automatically.

Thanks

Comment: You have a type in `computed`: `copmuted`.

Comment: How about doing a check at `created()` lifecycle event?

Comment: @Styx thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it. BTW you have a typo in your comment. :P

Comment: @YaswantNarayan Do I have access to the el instance during create lifecycle? can you explain with an example.

Comment: @PreritKimtani Thanks for pointing that :) I meant that this typo could cause the issues, since you've copied this text from the code... right?

Comment: @Styx actually the typo came when I was pasting the code blocks here but I cross checked with my code and it was perfect that side. :)

Comment: @PreritKimtani I see. Could you share your template as well?